# Cannot get response from node.js to react.js using GET call

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, reactjs

while using an Ajax call I am trying to get data from the back-end

```
 componentDidMount: function () {
         $.ajax({
         url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/ap/test',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            this.setState(data);
        }.bind(this),  error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            //   console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            console.error('failed to view user');
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

And here is my Get call in node.js

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {  DBs.find({},function(err,data){
if(err){ throw err;}
else {
  console.log('GET API CALLED, Data Sent!');
} sendingData = data;});   res.send(sendingData); });
```

1)API gets called but response isnt sent.('GET API CALLED, Data Sent!')

2)success function doesn't run in the Ajax call resulting in error: 'failed to view user'

Comment: Do you get a response from your node endpoint if you use curl?

Answer (score 1):

Your `DBs.find()` call will be `asynchronous` and hence you need to send data from the callback function of `DBs.find` like

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    DBs.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log('GET API CALLED, Data Sent!');
            res.send(data);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Still not getting the response. Used  `res.send(data);` like you said

Comment: can you console.log(data) in DB's callback, is it json

Comment: One more thing can you console.log(err) in ajax success call and share me the output

Comment: It runs but it's outputting nothing

Comment: Try logging xhr and see if you get something there

Answer (score 0):

@ShubhamKhatri is right in saying that the call to `res.send` should be inside the callback function, so that it runs after the result of the database lookup is known.

But there's another bug: you forgot to convert the result to a JSON string before sending it. Then `res.send` expects a string (or maybe a buffer), so I suppose it just sends `data.toString()`, which would be `[object Object]` or something similar. Since you've used `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery tries to read this as a JSON string. But it's not valid JSON, so the error function is called.

To fix this, just call `JSON.stringify`:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    DBs.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            // BTW you might want less drastic error handling in this case. I'd say just send an HTTP 500 response and log something.
        } else {
            console.log('GET API CALLED, Data Sent!');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
```